# Is it possible to use Next.js without SSR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am starting a project where I decided to use Next.js. But my manager doesn't want the app to be in SSR, as it needs a Node server. He wants it to be only SPA.

Now I can use `create-react-app` and create the app with React, but I was thinking of taking advantage of the Next.js routing and other built-in configs.

As I've seen in Nuxt.js, there is a way of using `'universal'` or `'spa'` [mode](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode), I am searching if there is any way to make `'spa'` in Next.js.

Comment: Your app would still be a SPA but when you deep link the SSR will get you the page faster. Your manager doesn't seem to understand what is what.

Comment: Actually he knows about it. But he doesn't want SSR.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it's possible. But that's not what it was built for and you're going to have a hard time keeping it a SPA. The Next routing and other built-in configs are specifically *for* SSR and creeping towards static site generation. `create-react-app` and things like React Router were built specifically *for* SPAs (though they're moving towards better SSR).

So if your boss wants a SPA, use the proper tool for it - today, that's CRA. You'll build it faster and meet the project requirements set forth by your boss. When the boss is ready for a SSR, consider Next. When the boss wants a static site built using React, consider Next or Gatsby.

Comment: Thank you. As I didn't get any straightway to do this, I've chosen to go with CRA.

Comment: It's 2023, even the official React docs don't support `create-react-app` anymore. Use Vite instead, that's the modern equivalent of CRA.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using nextjs’s static exports feature

be cautious! some others features are restricted(ssr, rewrite, etc) when using this feature

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports